# custom function works on page.php template but not in functions.php

Tags: functions, pages

I have a basic function attached to a button on the settings page of the dashboard

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_streamline'); 

function add_streamline() {
    add_options_page('Streamline', 'Streamline', 'manage_options', 'functions','create_streamline');
}

function create_streamline() { ?>
    
    <div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="update-streamline">
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
    </div>
<?php

}
```

Checking if the parameter set in the above form in is there ( *in functions.php* ) and then running a function based on that

```
if(isset($_POST['update-streamline'])){
    create_properties();
}
```

The create_properties() function is supposed to make a call to an API and just dump everything to the error log

```
function create_properties() {
    require(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/streamline_sdk/streamline.php' );

    $params = array();
    $params['status_id'] = 1;

    $test = streamline('GetPropertyList', $params );

    error_log($test);
}
```

When I click that button I created above in the backend I expect a bunch of data to get dumped into the error log but all I get is a blank Curl Error.

```
[20-Aug-2023 02:03:28 UTC] Curl error:
```

If I put the exact same code from the create_properties() functions into the page.php template I get the expected results in the error log of a bunch of dumped-out data.

What am I doing wrong in functions.php?

Ultimately, when that "update" button is clicked, I want to make some posts in a CPT based on data returned using wp_insert_post()

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the require from the create_properties solved the issue.

I also implemented the code from @ray-happyforms to adhere to the standard way of handling these types of calls.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got a fun challenge on your hands.

When you're checking `$_POST` directly in `functions.php`, it might be too early in the WordPress lifecycle for the data to be available, or the action may be bypassing the logic you're expecting.

Instead of using an empty action attribute in your form, it's typically best to handle admin-side form submissions with WordPress's `admin_post` action hook.

Change your form's action attribute to the following:

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="handle_update_streamline">
    <input type="hidden" name="update-streamline">
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Then, in your functions.php, you'll want to add:

```
add_action('admin_post_handle_update_streamline', 'my_streamline_update_handler');

function my_streamline_update_handler() {
    if(isset($_POST['update-streamline'])){
        create_properties();
    }
    // After processing, you might want to redirect somewhere like the settings page
    wp_redirect(admin_url('options-general.php?page=functions'));
    exit;
}
```

Give that a try! And don't forget to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: I did try the admin-post.php in the action was running into blank page issues because I was missing the wp_redirect, so thanks for that. The problem ended up being the require inside of the create_properties function. Moving that outside of the function resulted in the expected behavior.